# Is it possible to trigger JavaScript when a user selects the current option in an HTML select?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-select

I know that you can use the onchange event on the select to trigger a JavaScript function, but what if they choose the option that is currently selected?

The reason for this is I want to have a drop down list of a bunch of websites. This is used as a sort of jumppage, if you will. When the user selects a site the selected site opens in a new window. Now if they close the new tab/window the select is on the last option they selected. If the user wants to go to the same website again the onchange event does not fire.

I know that you can change the select option back to the default option with a null value like this:

**html**

```
<select onChange="jsFunction(this.value)" id="selectOpt">
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="websiteURL2">2</option>
    <option value="websiteURL3">3</option>
</select>
```

**javascript**

```
function jsFunction(opt){
    window.location = opt;
    document.getElementById("selectOpt").options[0].selected = true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XqLmY/1/

But I was wondering if it could be done without that.

Can I trigger an event using a HTML select without changing its value?

Comment: what you're describing shouldn't use a `<select>` element, as that's inappropriate. Instead you should use a list of links and style it. That way it performs consistently whether the user is using a desktop or mobile device, or if they're a keyboard only user.

Comment: I really don't want a flat list of links all showing at the same time because it is a long list.

Comment: I never said you should show a flat list of links all at the same time, I said you should use a list of links instead of the `<select>` element. You can still style the list and use javascript to toggle how it shows.

Comment: @zzzzBov Can you describe what you are suggesting here? Is it some sort of folding list?

Comment: @zzzzBov I was chatting with Luxelin and he suggested using the bootstrap dropdown; http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns. I think that kind of solution is what you may be suggesting as well, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but I just ended up using this method because it was easy and didn't have other dependencies.

```
function jsFunction(opt){
    window.location = opt;
    document.getElementById("selectOpt").options[0].selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using onClick instead 
Look here http://jsfiddle.net/9X4Ks/1/

```
<select onclick="clickFunction(this)" id="selectOpt">
    <option value="websiteURL1">1</option>
    <option value="websiteURL2">2</option>
    <option value="websiteURL3">3</option>
</select>

function clickFunction(o){
    alert(o.value)
}
```

It fires even when user clicks the selected option second time.
Unfortunately it works only in chrome and opera.
Does not work in firefox

Comment: This fires the event every time I click on the select only allowing me to choose the current option; even in Chrome.